# Why does ostringstream strip NULL?

Tags: c++, string-concatenation, ostringstream

I have a string whose last part(suffix) needs to be changed several times and I need to generate new strings. I am trying to use ostringstream to do this as I think, using streams will be faster than string concatenations. But when the previous suffix is greater than the later one, it gets messed up. The stream strips off null characters too.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ostringstream os;
  streampos pos;
  os << "Hello ";
  pos = os.tellp();
  os << "Universe";
  os.seekp(pos);
  cout<<  os.str() << endl;
  os << "World\0";
  cout<<  os.str().c_str() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello Universe
Hello Worldrse
```

But I want `Hello World`. How do I do this? Is there anyother way to do this in a faster manner?

**Edit:**
Appending `std::ends` works. But wondering how it works internally. Also like to know if there are faster ways to do the same.

Comment: No so sure that stringstream will be the most efficient - you should consider one of the variants of `std::string::replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't strip anything. All string literals in C++ are terminated by NUL, so by inserting one manually you just finish the string, as far as anyone processing it is concerned. Use `ostream::write` or `ostream::put`, if you need to do that — anything that expects `char*` (with no additional argument for size) will most likely treat it specially.

```
os.write("World\0", 6);
```

Answer (score 10):

The string "World" is already null-terminated. That's how C strings work. "World\0" has two `\0` characters. Therefore, `operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` will treat them the same, and copy all characters up to `\0`. You can see this even more clearly, if you try `os << "World\0!"`. The `!` will not be copied at all, since `operator<<` stopped at the first `\0`.

So, it's not `ostringstream`. It's how C strings aka `const char*` work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think a stream operation is faster than a string? And why build the string before outputting to cout?

If you want a prefix to your output you could just do it like this

```
const std::string prefix = "Hello ";

std::cout << prefix << "Universe" << std::endl;
std::cout << prefix << "World" << std::endl;
```